# When creating a multiple project template for visual studio is there a way to use parameters in the root template file?

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I am trying to create a multi project template.  I wish the sub projects names to contain the solution name.  I have tried the following however $safeprojectName$ doesn't work in the root template for some reason.  It tries to create the folders with $safeprojectName$ in the name rather than the actual project name.

```xml
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Default Solution</Name>
    <Description>An example of a multi-project template</Description>
    <Icon>Icon.ico</Icon>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <SolutionFolder Name="$safeprojectName$.Web">
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectName$.Web">
          Src\Web\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
      </SolutionFolder>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

I have done a lot of reading on this and have and have created an assembly using the IWizard interface that creates a parameter $solutionName$.  I then used the following template.

```xml
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Default Solution</Name>
    <Description>An example of a multi-project template</Description>
    <Icon>Icon.ico</Icon>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <SolutionFolder Name="$solutionName$.Web">
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$solutionName$.Web">
          Src\Web\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
      </SolutionFolder>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>DefaultSoloutionWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=f753ddb61a28cb36, processorArchitecture=MSIL</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>DefaultSoloutionWizard.WizardImplementation</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

This however also fails with the same problem.  I'm I trying to do the impossible? Any help on this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into the [Guidance Automation Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687174.aspx). There's a fair amount to digest there, but part of what it can do is put a Wizard-based UI on a multi-project template.

If you want to see an example of that, take a look at the [Service Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/servicefactory/), which can create an entire solution structure based in part on a wizard.

Answer (score 5):

As of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 you can now use the CopyParameters attribute on the ProjectTemplateLink element in the root .vstemplate file.  Any parameters defined in the root template will be available in the linked templates with a "ext_" prefix.

For example, if the root template defines a parameter, $Foo$, then the parameter $ext_Foo$ will be available in the linked projects with the same value.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171398.aspx for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use a static dictionary in the wizard of root template, which will be used by the wizard implementation of child templates:

IWizard implementation in root template

```cs
public void RunStarted(object automationObject,
        Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary,
        WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
    {
        try
        {
            // Display a form to the user. The form collects 
            // input for the custom message.
            inputForm = new UserInputForm();
            inputForm.ShowDialog();

            customMessage = inputForm.get_CustomMessage();

            // Add custom parameters.
            replacementsDictionary.Add("$custommessage$",
                customMessage);
            globalDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            globalDictionary.Add("$custommessage$",
                customMessage);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, string> globalDictionary;
```

You can get the complete example implemented here: [Multi-Project Templates with Wizard: Visual Studio 2010 Sample](http://vsix.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Running that project in Debug BSOD'd my VS 2010 SP 1

Comment: This does not help get Solution Folders with parametrized names.